# Display an image from a blob field - Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, image, blob

I have to show a picture stored in a mysql database (in a blob field) in a JLabel or anything else to show it. 
after writing this line, what should I do?

```
Blob b = rs.getBlob ("image");
```

please explain in detail, I have searched all over the site but have not managed to finish anything. thanks in advance to all.

PS: I ask the administrators to not put off topic immediately because otherwise I can not replicate, thank you :) .

stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
Finger was removed from fingerprint reader
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
at AppMain.ExtractDB(AppMain.java:294)
at AppMain.initDB(AppMain.java:271)
at AppMain.initialize(AppMain.java:245)
at AppMain.<init>(AppMain.java:68)
at MainForm.identify(MainForm.java:356)
at MainForm.extract(MainForm.java:257)
at MainForm.onImageAcquired(MainForm.java:213)
at com.griaule.grfingerjava.GrFingerJavaNative.callbackImage(GrFingerJavaNative.java:157)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read BLOB's input stream and convert it to byte[] like this:

```
InputStream byte_stream = b.getBinaryStream();
byte [] byte_array = new byte [byte_stream.available()];
int bytes_read = byte_stream.read(byte_array);
```

And than use this byte_array to create ImageIcon and set into JLabel like this:

**Another Way using ImageIO**

```
InputStream in = b.getBinaryStream();
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(in)));
```

Hope this will give you right direction to resolve your issue

Comment: hello, first of all thanks for the quick response, then I wanted to say that it return me an error. in a few words the programs underlines me this line in red: new ImageIcon (bytes_read)

Comment: whats the message it gives?

Comment: when I write this: JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bytes_read)); it return me an error. it is as if he does not accept "bytes_read"

Comment: sorry my mistake, just updated answer, it was a typo

Comment: thank you very much, really, but does not show it ... why? :/

Comment: debug your code and look if you are getting complete byte_array or try alternate way i added

Comment: ok, so when I try this: label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(in))); it return me an error: java.lang.NullPointerException but the image is loaded!

Comment: Please post stack trace